# All electron apps crash me to login screen

Tags: xorg, segmentation-fault, electron

Basically, as the title says, any electron app I try to run (atom, slack and vscode specifically) crash me out to the desktop. I was able to run slack for a long time on my machine, but when I installed vscode it started to cause this issue where it would crash me out to desktop. After that happened, slack started doing the same.

After a lot of faffing about, I decided to just re-install Ubuntu (I am not a tech wizard) because I figured something must've been broken but now any electron-based app will just crash me out to desktop.

From my (limited) experience, I think I've worked out it's something like a segmentation fault in xorg, here is what I'm seeing in `journalctl`

```
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE)
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) Backtrace:
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x5580ab70d37d]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5580ab555000+0x1bc119) [0x5580ab711119]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fc15c7fb000+0x13150) [0x7fc15c80e150]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x22fcb6) [0x7fc152dd1cb6]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x19a829) [0x7fc152d3c829]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x12e272) [0x7fc152cd0272]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x12e2ae) [0x7fc152cd02ae]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x12e311) [0x7fc152cd0311]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x98152) [0x7fc152c3a152]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x23c63b) [0x7fc152dde63b]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x3b3afd) [0x7fc152f55afd]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (0x7fc152ba2000+0x3b2bd3) [0x7fc152f54bd3]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (0x7fc15a7d2000+0x2f129) [0x7fc15a801129]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (0x7fc15a7d2000+0x26b65) [0x7fc15a7f8b65]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5580ab555000+0x77952) [0x5580ab5cc952]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (0x7fc15a7d2000+0x229a7) [0x7fc15a7f49a7]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (0x7fc15a7d2000+0x26e2c) [0x7fc15a7f8e2c]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 17: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5580ab555000+0x52e28) [0x5580ab5a7e28]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 18: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5580ab555000+0x56e70) [0x5580ab5abe70]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7fc15c43c1c1]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x5580ab595b2a]
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE)
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x70
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE)
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: Fatal server error:
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE)
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]:  for help.
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/byron/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE)
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
Mar 18 01:21:29 Erazer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4668]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Please let me know if I need to include more/what to include.

Thanks!